# Find roots of a specific discontinuous trigonometric function

Tags: number-theory, trigonometry

Given the following function $f(x)$ and an arbitrary positive non-prime integer $N$

$ \{ f(x) = \sin(N\pi/x) + \cos(2N\pi/x) + |sin(3N\pi/x)| + |cos(5N\pi/x)| + 1, N \in \mathbb{Z}, x \in \mathbb{R} \}  $

I am looking for any root in the range $2 <= x < N$, I am pretty sure all $f(x)$ are greater than or equal to zero, so the roots are global minima. All the roots are also points of discontinuity and their $x \in \mathbb{Z} $.

### Question

Is there any, even numerical way, to go about finding these roots for any arbitrary non-prime N? Or even just point me in the right direction like an algorithm name, I'm a software engineer, and familiar with arbitrary precision libraries like GMP, so I can implement numerical methods if I can understand the math.

Here is a plot of $f(x)$ for $N=517$. It isn't very good, its hard to choose a zoom level which will demonstrate all the features. But you can see I marked a zero at $x=22$, you will notice it looks like there is a zero at $x \approx 26.5$ but it is actually $ f(x) \approx 0.0011 $ if one were to zoom in.

There are many of these "close" to zero points, but none are actually zero, in the range I'm interested in ($ 2<=x<N $), unless 2 conditions I have found are met:

1. $x \in \mathbb{Z} $
2. $GCD(x,N) > 1 $

My example $N=517$ the roots are $ x \in \{-2,22,94\} $, we don't care about $-2$ and $GCD(22,517)=11$ and $GCD(94,517) = 47$.

I don't think the GCD observation will help in finding the roots, but I mention it because I think its interesting. And if anyone has an insight as to why this GCD relationship exists but not the main question still feel free to answer.

[image: Plot of function for N = 517]

Here is another plot, in response to @poetasis comment below. I zoomed out to show a little better that all values of $f(x)$ are greater than zero except 3 points which are equal to zero where $ x \in \{-2, 22, 94 \} $ though its only really easy to see $ f(94) = 0 $ at this zoom level.

Also notice the period is not regular or an integer, it gets larger as we move right. The zeroes occur at those M-shaped downward "spikes". The spikes occurring where x is an integer actually touch the zero line, like at $ x = 94 $, the others occurring off an integer like the one around $ x = 147.7 $ can be close but not zero $ f(147.7) = 0.00859 $.

I put in some $x$ and $f(x)$ values of the M-shaped spikes so you can see below. There are other spikes, they all occur on non-integer $x$'s as well and have non-zero $f(x)$

In case its too hard to read, for N=517

$f(22)=0$

$f(38.3)=0.0767$

$f(68.96)=0.0480$

$f(94)=0$

$f(147.7)=0.00859$

[image: Zoomed in Plot]

Comment: $$x = \frac{2 N}{4 n - 1} \quad\text{for}\quad N\ne0 \land n \in\mathbb{ Z}$$

Comment: @poetasis, thank your for your comment, but I'm not sure I understand. You say $$ x = \frac{2N}{4n-1} $$ for $$N \neq 0 \wedge n \in \mathbb{Z} $$ Is that supposed to give the x's of the roots?

Comment: Given some non-zero $N$, and any integer $n$, I believe these values will yield integers for the expression. Example, for $\quad N=3\land n=1\rightarrow x=2.\quad$ I believe all the trig terms will be using multiples of $\pi/2$ and the calculations should be relatively easy.

Comment: @poetasis - If you look at a plot of the function though it is not cyclic with a regular period like a simple trig function.

Comment: I'm simply saying that this should provide values of $x$ that provide convenient fractions of $\pi$ for ease of calculations as opposed to points of discontinuity. I should also have mentioned (but you did) $N\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @poestasis - oh I see, convenient fractions of $\pi$ instead of all the reals.

Answer (score 1):

This will be easier if you substitute $t=\frac{1}{x}$ and graph it as a function of $t$.

Looking at the zeros of the $t$ function, you will see that for each $N$, they form an arithmetic progression whose terms are easily discernible.

For example, here is the graph of $f(t)$ for $N=4$.

[image: Graph of f(t) for N=4]

It is not difficult to work out that the first zero is always

$$ t_0(N)=\frac{3}{2N} $$

and that the common difference of the sequence of zeroes is

$$ d=\frac{2}{N} $$

So the $k$th zero for $N$ will be

$$ t_k(N)= \frac{3+4k}{2N} $$

The reciprocals of these will be the zeros of $f(x)$.

$$ x_k(N)=\frac{2N}{3+4k} $$

Note that $x_{11}(517)=22$.

Comment: Thank you for your response @John Wayland Bales. Let me clarify my motivation in creating the function, I was trying to make a function to factorize integers. I realize its a pipe dream, alot of people alot smarter than me have thought about it alot longer, but just something to do. I was hoping I could create a function that was differentiable, or at least had some rhyme or reason to it, where the roots or something other aspect I could get the factors for an arbitrary composite integer. Continued in next comment ...

Comment: I started with $$f(x)=sin(\frac{N\pi}{x})$$ which has many zeroes (roots), its integer factors are in the set of roots. But it has many many roots, checking them all is no faster than factoring. So I kept tweaking it until I came up with the function in my original post, which only has roots on integers, and all positive roots of the function have a GCD with N that is non-trivial, and calculating GCD is really fast so essentially if I can find the roots I can factor the integer. But trying to find the roots of a discontinuous function like that is out of my skill range.

Comment: I wish you luck.